# Docker / Visual Studio changing code why does Untracked not updated

Tags: docker

So I am new to Docker, I have a simple web server running in docker.

I make a change in my Visual Studio Code and it shows "Untracked" in the file tab, when I refresh my web page these changes are not showing.
I watched a few online tutorials on Docker on Youtube hoping I can get more info on how to use Docker and get more familiarized with this issue, sadly this was not a topic of discussion.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: Docker normally runs off of an isolated and immutable image, and you need to rebuild your image and recreate your container to see changes in your code base.  Have you done this?

Comment: No, thank you for that - so there is no real way to dev using docker and show live changes - I understand creating a build and why its built this way?